# Assigning values to a new user from a view

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-views

I have an application fileman with models.py like so:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from fileman.fields import AutoForeignKey

from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

class Setting(models.Model):
    owner = AutoForeignKey(User, unique=True, related_name='fileman_Setting')
    root = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    home = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    buffer = models.TextField(blank=True)
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("can_fm_list", _("Can look files list")),
            ("can_fm_add", _("Can upload files")),
            ("can_fm_rename", _("Can rename files")),
            ("can_fm_del", _("Can move files to basket")),
            ("can_fm_destruct", _("Can delete files")),
        )
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.owner)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Setting, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if not self.root:
            self.root = None
            self.home = None
    def writeBuffer(self, data):
        self.buffer = data
        self.save()
```

I want to assign root, home and permissions for a user when he registers: This is what I have in userprofile/views.py

```
from fileman.models import Setting

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            newuser = User.objects.create_user(username=username, email='', password=password)

            if form.cleaned_data.get('email'):
                newuser.email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
                EmailValidation.objects.add(user=newuser, email=newuser.email)
            newuser.save()
            # Fileman Settings
            newuser.fileman_Setting.owner = newuser
            newuser.fileman_Setting.root = '/home/aton2/ajunkkil/Django/basedraft/uploads'
            print(newuser.fileman_Setting.root)
            newuser.fileman_Setting.home = '/home/aton2/ajunkkil/Django/basedraft/uploads/useruploads'
            print(newuser.fileman_Setting.home)
            newuser.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('%scomplete/' % request.path_info)
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()

    template = "userprofile/account/registration.html"
    data = { 'form': form, }
    return render_to_response(template, data, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The application has a feature in admin that allows one to set the root and home folders for the users there. But I want it to happen automatically when a user registers. I get the owner just fine but home and root remain as 'None' even though `print(newuser.fileman_Setting.root)` is correct. What am I missing?

fileman/admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from fileman.models import *

class SettingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   list_display = ('owner', 'root', 'home')

admin.site.register(Setting, SettingAdmin)
```

Comment: Format your source code properly - it's unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save `newuser.fileman_Setting` too, because django won't save changes to models automatically.

Comment: Thanks, newuser.fileman_Setting.save() worked. How do I add permissions for new users using that same class Setting?

Comment: via admin or as described here http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#methods

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea what `AutoForeignKey` does, but assuming it's similar to a standard ForeignKey, the reverse `fileman_Setting` refers to a QuerySet.

A ForeignKey is a one-to-many relationship, where the one is the side that defines the FK, and the reverse relationship - accessed via the name assigned in `related_name` - is the many, so is represented by a QuerySet. So instead of setting the home and root fields on an individual Setting, you're defining arbitrary attributes on a QuerySet, which are then ignored.

It sounds like you probably want a OneToOneField here, in any case. Once you've done that, then as Dmitry says you'll need to remember to save it.

Comment: How do I assign the permissions from the Settings class Meta to a user?